# Is this an issue with my firewall or chrome? Xmlhttprequest to C# listener error

Tags: c#, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, firewall

I have a Httplistener set up in C# that reads the Get parameters and performs an action, just a small personal project. Now, when I send the requests from an HTML page in chrome with 127.0.0.1:port it works fine. But if I use my full IP (the one i get from googling my IP), the xmlhttp request fails. Same when I host the file on my site. Is this an issue with Chrome or my firewall settings? I opened the port to all connections and excused Visual Studio from my firewall as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address that you get from Google (or wherever) is your IP address to the internet.  On your network, you will most likely have an IP address for your network that is different than your internet address.

I did a google search and found [this page](http://kb.iu.edu/data/aapa.html) to help you follow the steps required by various operating systems to determine what your computer's IP address is.

As an alternative to using an IP address, you can use your computer's name.

If you want to use your internet IP address so that you can access your site from the internet and not just your network, you'll need to set up [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).

Comment: The goal here is to be able to make the request to your computer on an address different from 127.0.0.1, correct?  If so, you need to use your computer's IP address, and not your network's internet address.  You can follow the link in the answer above to see instructions on how to find your computer's IP address.

Comment: Yeah, nvm, some other error there, works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up port forwarding on your router.

Comment: Is there an alternative? I don't have access to those privileges that on my router